# CMD or batch command to read Serial COM

Tags: batch-file, cmd, serial-port

I need to make a simple script to run on CMD (or batch).

The code should send a line over Serial Port (COM#), wait for the port to answer, verify its answer and if it matches, continue with the code.

I already got the "send" part:

`set /p x="TEST" <nul >\\.\COM#`

I just need help with the rest. Any contribution is welcome.

Comment: didn't try, but `set /p "answer=" <COM#` should work if the answer is also just one line.

Answer (score 1):

Thumbs up to Stephan, he actually found a good answer for me

> didn't try, but `set /p "answer=" <COM#` should work if the answer is also just one line.